# Node.js application not loadingproperly in Chromium: Connection timed out while reading response header from upstream

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm running a Node.JS application in the subdomain of WP site. The WP site itself is running on Nginx, php-fpm and Varnish and works just fine, so I'm using Nginx to proxy connections to the Node app.

With Firefox, the Node app works perfectly. The home page and every other page loads, including the admin end. However, on Chromium, the site does not load properly. If I attempt to view the home page, the main content area loads, but the sidebar does not. And I get the following message in the Web console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://forum.site.com/socket.io/1/websocket/91qNR-mt333a' 
failed: Unexpected response code: 502
```

In the Nginx log file, I see entries like:

```
2089 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream,
client: 127.0.0.1, server: forum.site.com, request: "GET /socket.io/1/websocket/91qNR-
mt333a HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4567/socket.io/1/websocket/91qNRaWZ3-
mt333a", host: "forum.site.com"
```

And if I try to navigate between posts on the site, I get these messages in the Web console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)
http://forum.site.com/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/91qNRaWZ3rYcF-mt333a?t=1396434040701
```

Then these lines from Nginx error log:

```
2128 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from
upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: forum.site.com, request: "GET /socket.io/1/xhr-
polling/uH9QTAWUGmomqFoy333e?t=1396434162051 HTTP/1.1", upstream:
"http://127.0.0.1:4567/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/uH9QTAWUGmomqFoy333e?t=1396434162051",
host: "forum.site.com", referrer: "http://forum.site.com/category/35/dual-boots"
```

I've looked at similar issues on this site and other sites and tried to implement the suggested solutions, but no luck so far. For example, in the Nginx config for the subdomain, I've added the following:

```
proxy_buffers 8 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 64k;
proxy_connect_timeout       120;
proxy_read_timeout          300;
```

And played around with different values for the last two lines, but still no luck.

What baffles me is that the site works perfectly on FF. It's only on Chromium that I'm having these problem. I've not tried on IE, but I'm not really concerned about that browser at this point.

I'm sure there's something that I'm overlooking, but I don't know what.

Btw, the site exhibits the same behavior on Android's default browser.

Could Varnish be the culprit here. I have Varnish (port 80) in front of Nginx (8080). Does Varnish play nice with WebSockets?

Comment: What versions of the various browsers and what version of Nginx are you using? Is it also not working with Chrome?

Comment: FF 28 and Chromium 33. Same issue with Chromium 27, so I'm assuming same on any version of Chromium between 27 and 33. Nginx is 1.4.7

Comment: Could Varnish be the culprit here. I have Varnish (port 80) in front of Nginx (8080). Does Varnish play nice with WebSockets?

Comment: Yep, Varnish is the culprit. See my answer below.

Comment: Why did it work in Firefox then? I assumed it wasn't Varnish because it was working in one browser but not the other.

Comment: That's a good question, which I can't really answer properly. What I can say, though, is that even though it was working on FF, it was still showing similar errors in the Web console. So there must be something about FF that Chromium/Chrome lack. The most VIP thing is that after setting up Varnish to handle WebSocket traffic, it now works on all the browsers. And no errors in the Web consoles. That's probably why FF is my preferred browser.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that the problem is with Varnish, which by default does not handle WebSocket traffic. It has to be explicitly configured for it.

See [this link](http://forum.linuxbsdos.com/topic/184/how-to-configure-varnish-for-websocket-traffic) for the solution.